# How to simplify this simple JS script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, simplify

I'd like to know how I could make the code shorter by not repeating everything basically 4 times (each for every individual .section1-item).
I'd like to know if there is a syntax or something that could make the code look cleaner and most of all not so redundant.
I'm very new to JS and I'd like to learn more about it, and how I could make it more optimised.

- When clicked, a card must get the class .active-card and the 3 others must not this same class.
- When active, a card img must have the "images/tcheen-logo-jaune.png" , and the 3 others must have the "images/tcheen-logo-white.png".

```js
const section1Card1 = document.querySelector(
    ".section1-col:nth-of-type(1) .section1-item:nth-child(1)"
);
const section1Card2 = document.querySelector(
    ".section1-col:nth-of-type(1) .section1-item:nth-child(2)"
);
const section1Card3 = document.querySelector(
    ".section1-col:nth-of-type(3) .section1-item:nth-child(1)"
);
const section1Card4 = document.querySelector(
    ".section1-col:nth-of-type(3) .section1-item:nth-child(2)"
);
//
const section1Card1Img = document.querySelector(
    ".section1-col:nth-of-type(1) .section1-item:nth-child(1) img"
);
const section1Card2Img = document.querySelector(
    ".section1-col:nth-of-type(1) .section1-item:nth-child(2) img"
);
const section1Card3Img = document.querySelector(
    ".section1-col:nth-of-type(3) .section1-item:nth-child(1) img"
);
const section1Card4Img = document.querySelector(
    ".section1-col:nth-of-type(3) .section1-item:nth-child(2) img"
);
//
const cardIndexDot1 = document.querySelector(".image-index-dot:nth-of-type(1)");
const cardIndexDot2 = document.querySelector(".image-index-dot:nth-of-type(2)");
const cardIndexDot3 = document.querySelector(".image-index-dot:nth-of-type(3)");
const cardIndexDot4 = document.querySelector(".image-index-dot:nth-of-type(4)");
//
const section1Cards = document.querySelectorAll(".section1-item");
const section1CardsImg = document.querySelectorAll(".section1-item img");

section1Card1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("bon");
    if (!section1Card1.classList.contains("active-card")) {
        section1Card2.classList.remove("active-card");
        section1Card3.classList.remove("active-card");
        section1Card4.classList.remove("active-card");
        section1CardsImg.src = "images/tcheen-logo-white.png";
        section1Card1.classList.add("active-card");
        section1Card1Img.src = "images/tcheen-logo-jaune.png";
        cardIndexDot1.classList.add("image-index-dot-active");
        cardIndexDot2.classList.remove("image-index-dot-active");
        cardIndexDot3.classList.remove("image-index-dot-active");
        cardIndexDot4.classList.remove("image-index-dot-active");
        console.log("oui");
    }
});
section1Card2.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("bon");
    if (!section1Card2.classList.contains("active-card")) {
        section1Card1.classList.remove("active-card");
        section1Card3.classList.remove("active-card");
        section1Card4.classList.remove("active-card");
        section1CardsImg.src = "images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png";
        section1Card2.classList.add("active-card");
        section1Card2Img.src = "images/tcheen-logo-jaune.png";
        cardIndexDot2.classList.add("image-index-dot-active");
        cardIndexDot1.classList.remove("image-index-dot-active");
        cardIndexDot3.classList.remove("image-index-dot-active");
        cardIndexDot4.classList.remove("image-index-dot-active");
        console.log("oui");
    }
});
section1Card3.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("bon");
    if (!section1Card3.classList.contains("active-card")) {
        section1Card1.classList.remove("active-card");
        section1Card2.classList.remove("active-card");
        section1Card4.classList.remove("active-card");
        section1CardsImg.src = "images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png";
        section1Card3.classList.add("active-card");
        section1Card3Img.src = "images/tcheen-logo-jaune.png";
        cardIndexDot3.classList.add("image-index-dot-active");
        cardIndexDot2.classList.remove("image-index-dot-active");
        cardIndexDot1.classList.remove("image-index-dot-active");
        cardIndexDot4.classList.remove("image-index-dot-active");
        console.log("oui");
    }
});
section1Card4.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("bon");
    if (!section1Card4.classList.contains("active-card")) {
        section1Card1.classList.remove("active-card");
        section1Card2.classList.remove("active-card");
        section1Card3.classList.remove("active-card");
        section1CardsImg.src = "images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png";
        section1Card4.classList.add("active-card");
        section1Card4Img.src = "images/tcheen-logo-jaune.png";
        cardIndexDot4.classList.add("image-index-dot-active");
        cardIndexDot2.classList.remove("image-index-dot-active");
        cardIndexDot3.classList.remove("image-index-dot-active");
        cardIndexDot1.classList.remove("image-index-dot-active");
        console.log("oui");
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins";
}

:root {
    --color-yellow: #efd858;
    --color-pink: #eebcd8;
    --color-green: #6cbe99;
    --color-black: #1a1a1a;
    --color-white: #ffffff;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/*  */
.yellow-bg {
    background-color: var(--color-yellow);
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

/*  */
.section1 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 40px;
    padding-top: 98px;
}

.section1-col {
    width: 20%;
}

.section1-img {
    width: 27%;
}

.section1-img img {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.section1-item {
    padding: 30px 18px 80px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: var(--color-green);
}

.section1-item:nth-of-type(odd) {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.section1-item img {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 18px;
    right: 18px;
    width: 12.5%;
}

.section1-item h3 {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    width: 75%;
}

.section1-item p {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
}

.image-index {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -36px;
    width: 120px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-index-dot {
    width: 15px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: var(--color-black);
}

/*  */
.active-card {
    background: var(--color-yellow);
}

.image-index-dot-active {
    background: var(--color-yellow);
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
    <div class="section1-col">
        <article class="section1-item active-card">
            <img src="images/tcheen-logo-jaune.png" alt="Tcheen Logo">
            <h3>Eco-responsable et original</h3>
            <p>La crème des prestataires sensibilisés à l’engagement durable.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="section1-item">
            <img src="images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png" alt="Tcheen Logo">
            <h3>Devis instantané</h3>
            <p>Obtenez le match parfait et votre devis en 2 minutes chrono !</p>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="section1-img">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/390x500/?space,planet" alt="Image 1">
    </div>
    <div class="section1-col">
        <article class="section1-item">
            <img src="images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png" alt="Tcheen Logo">
            <h3>100% Transparent</h3>
            <p>Nos frais de service sont transparents et sans surcoût sur vos prestations.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="section1-item">
            <img src="images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png" alt="Tcheen Logo">
            <h3>Accompagnement personnalisé</h3>
            <p>Nous vous accompagnons de A à Z avant et pendant votre événement.</p>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="image-index">
        <div class="image-index-dot image-index-dot-active"></div>
        <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
        <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
        <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML with us? There's a very good chance that this could be made much easier - as you request - but I expect that the best approach (for whatever value of "best" you might define) will depend on the structure of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boil the JS down to a few lines by taking a more general approach.

You can find the collection of all those articles by selecting on their class and then stepping through them all adding a click event listener.

When you execute a listener it knows the index of the item that has been clicked and so can add the active class and relevant logo image and also add the right class to the relevant dot.

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.section1 > .section1-col .section1-item');
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.section1 > .image-index > .image-index-dot');
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      items[j].classList.remove('active-card');
      items[j].querySelector('img').src = 'images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png';
      dots[j].classList.remove('image-index-dot-active');
    }
    items[i].classList.add('active-card');
    items[i].querySelector('img').src = 'images/tcheen-logo-jaune.png';
    dots[i].classList.add('image-index-dot-active');
  });
}
```

Here's the full snippet which does not alter your CSS or your HTML:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.section1 > .section1-col .section1-item');
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.section1 > .image-index > .image-index-dot');
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      items[j].classList.remove('active-card');
      items[j].querySelector('img').src = 'images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png';
      dots[j].classList.remove('image-index-dot-active');
    }
    items[i].classList.add('active-card');
    items[i].querySelector('img').src = 'images/tcheen-logo-jaune.png';
    dots[i].classList.add('image-index-dot-active');
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

:root {
  --color-yellow: #efd858;
  --color-pink: #eebcd8;
  --color-green: #6cbe99;
  --color-black: #1a1a1a;
  --color-white: #ffffff;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/*  */

.yellow-bg {
  background-color: var(--color-yellow);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}


/*  */

.section1 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 40px;
  padding-top: 98px;
}

.section1-col {
  width: 20%;
}

.section1-img {
  width: 27%;
}

.section1-img img {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.section1-item {
  padding: 30px 18px 80px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: var(--color-green);
}

.section1-item:nth-of-type(odd) {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.section1-item img {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 18px;
  right: 18px;
  width: 12.5%;
}

.section1-item h3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
  width: 75%;
}

.section1-item p {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.image-index {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -36px;
  width: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-index-dot {
  width: 15px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: var(--color-black);
}


/*  */

.active-card {
  background: var(--color-yellow);
}

.image-index-dot-active {
  background: var(--color-yellow);
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <div class="section1-col">
    <article class="section1-item active-card">
      <img src="images/tcheen-logo-jaune.png" alt="Tcheen Logo">
      <h3>Eco-responsable et original</h3>
      <p>La crème des prestataires sensibilisés à l’engagement durable.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="section1-item">
      <img src="images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png" alt="Tcheen Logo">
      <h3>Devis instantané</h3>
      <p>Obtenez le match parfait et votre devis en 2 minutes chrono !</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="section1-img">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/390x500/?space,planet" alt="Image 1">
  </div>
  <div class="section1-col">
    <article class="section1-item">
      <img src="images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png" alt="Tcheen Logo">
      <h3>100% Transparent</h3>
      <p>Nos frais de service sont transparents et sans surcoût sur vos prestations.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="section1-item">
      <img src="images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png" alt="Tcheen Logo">
      <h3>Accompagnement personnalisé</h3>
      <p>Nous vous accompagnons de A à Z avant et pendant votre événement.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="image-index">
    <div class="image-index-dot image-index-dot-active"></div>
    <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
    <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
    <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
  </div>
</section>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another shortened way of doing it.

The `element.classList.toggle()` method adds or removes a specified className to the element's classList, depending on the second argument being truthy or not.

```js
const [items,dots]=[".section1-item",".image-index-dot"].map(cls=>document.querySelectorAll(cls));
items.forEach(itm=>
 itm.addEventListener("click",ev=>{
  items.forEach((it,i)=>{
   it.classList.toggle("active-card",it===itm);
   dots[i].classList.toggle("image-index-dot-active",it===itm);
  });
 })  
);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins";
}

:root {
    --color-yellow: #efd858;
    --color-pink: #eebcd8;
    --color-green: #6cbe99;
    --color-black: #1a1a1a;
    --color-white: #ffffff;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/*  */
.yellow-bg {
    background-color: var(--color-yellow);
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

/*  */
.section1 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 40px;
    padding-top: 98px;
}

.section1-col {
    width: 20%;
}

.section1-img {
    width: 27%;
}

.section1-img img {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.section1-item {
    padding: 30px 18px 80px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: var(--color-green);
}

.section1-item:nth-of-type(odd) {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.section1-item img {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 18px;
    right: 18px;
    width: 12.5%;
}

.section1-item h3 {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    width: 75%;
}

.section1-item p {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
}

.image-index {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -36px;
    width: 120px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-index-dot {
    width: 15px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: var(--color-black);
}

/*  */
.active-card {
    background: var(--color-yellow);
}

.image-index-dot-active {
    background: var(--color-yellow);
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
    <div class="section1-col">
        <article class="section1-item active-card">
            <img src="images/tcheen-logo-jaune.png" alt="Tcheen Logo">
            <h3>Eco-responsable et original</h3>
            <p>La crème des prestataires sensibilisés à l’engagement durable.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="section1-item">
            <img src="images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png" alt="Tcheen Logo">
            <h3>Devis instantané</h3>
            <p>Obtenez le match parfait et votre devis en 2 minutes chrono !</p>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="section1-img">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/390x500/?space,planet" alt="Image 1">
    </div>
    <div class="section1-col">
        <article class="section1-item">
            <img src="images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png" alt="Tcheen Logo">
            <h3>100% Transparent</h3>
            <p>Nos frais de service sont transparents et sans surcoût sur vos prestations.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="section1-item">
            <img src="images/tcheen-logo-blanc.png" alt="Tcheen Logo">
            <h3>Accompagnement personnalisé</h3>
            <p>Nous vous accompagnons de A à Z avant et pendant votre événement.</p>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="image-index">
        <div class="image-index-dot image-index-dot-active"></div>
        <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
        <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
        <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Loop through each `.section1-item` element, and add a click listener to it.
2. Remove `.active-class` from all `.section1-item` elements.
3. Add `.active-class` to the clicked element.
4. Use a pseudo-class to set the image. I removed the images from the `section` and instead added a ::before in the CSS.

```js
const section1Cards = document.querySelectorAll(".section1-item");

for (section1Card of section1Cards) {
  section1Card.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
     let clickedCard = event.currentTarget;
     for (_secCard of section1Cards) {
       _secCard.classList.remove('active-card');
     }
     
     clickedCard.classList.add('active-card');
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

:root {
  --color-yellow: #efd858;
  --color-pink: #eebcd8;
  --color-green: #6cbe99;
  --color-black: #1a1a1a;
  --color-white: #ffffff;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/*  */

.yellow-bg {
  background-color: var(--color-yellow);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}


/*  */

.section1 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 40px;
  padding-top: 98px;
}

.section1-col {
  width: 20%;
}

.section1-img {
  width: 27%;
}

.section1-img img {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.section1-item {
  padding: 30px 18px 80px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: var(--color-green);
}

.section1-item:nth-of-type(odd) {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.section1-item h3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
  width: 75%;
}

.section1-item p {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.image-index {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -36px;
  width: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-index-dot {
  width: 15px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: var(--color-black);
}



.active-card {
  background: var(--color-yellow);
}

/* ADDED */

.section1-item::before {
  content: url('https://via.placeholder.com/90x90.png?text=Blanc');
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 18px;
  right: 18px;
  width: 12.5%;
}

/* ADDED */

.section1-item.active-card::before {
  content: url('https://via.placeholder.com/90/8f8.png/000/?text=Jaune');
}

.image-index-dot-active {
  background: var(--color-yellow);
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <div class="section1-col">
    <article class="section1-item active-card">
      <h3>Eco-responsable et original</h3>
      <p>La crème des prestataires sensibilisés à l’engagement durable.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="section1-item">
      <h3>Devis instantané</h3>
      <p>Obtenez le match parfait et votre devis en 2 minutes chrono !</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="section1-img">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/390x500/?space,planet" alt="Image 1">
  </div>
  <div class="section1-col">
    <article class="section1-item">
      <h3>100% Transparent</h3>
      <p>Nos frais de service sont transparents et sans surcoût sur vos prestations.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="section1-item">
      <h3>Accompagnement personnalisé</h3>
      <p>Nous vous accompagnons de A à Z avant et pendant votre événement.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="image-index">
    <div class="image-index-dot image-index-dot-active"></div>
    <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
    <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
    <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The code above is only taking care of the sections. I would like to take the opportunity to show how to add/remove classes by using querySelect, instead of looping through all the `.image-index-dot` elements as I did with `.section1-item`.

```js
const section1Cards = document.querySelectorAll(".section1-item");

for (let section1Card of section1Cards) {
  section1Card.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
     let clickedCard = event.currentTarget;
     let index = 0, startsCountAtOne = 1;
     let activeCardClass = 'active-card';
     let activeDotClass = 'image-index-dot-active';

     for (let [_index, _secCard] of section1Cards.entries()) {
        if (_secCard !== clickedCard) {
          _secCard.classList.remove(activeCardClass);
        } else {
          _secCard.classList.add(activeCardClass);
          index = _index + startsCountAtOne;
        }
     }

     let activeDot = document.querySelector('.image-index > .' + activeDotClass);
     let clickedDot = document.querySelector(`.image-index > :nth-child(${index})`)
     
     activeDot.classList.remove(activeDotClass);
     clickedDot.classList.add(activeDotClass);
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

:root {
  --color-yellow: #efd858;
  --color-pink: #eebcd8;
  --color-green: #6cbe99;
  --color-black: #1a1a1a;
  --color-white: #ffffff;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/*  */

.yellow-bg {
  background-color: var(--color-yellow);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}


/*  */

.section1 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 40px;
  padding-top: 98px;
}

.section1-col {
  width: 20%;
}

.section1-img {
  width: 27%;
}

.section1-img img {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.section1-item {
  padding: 30px 18px 80px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: var(--color-green);
}

.section1-item:nth-of-type(odd) {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.section1-item h3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
  width: 75%;
}

.section1-item p {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.image-index {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -36px;
  width: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-index-dot {
  width: 15px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: var(--color-black);
}



.active-card {
  background: var(--color-yellow);
}

/* ADDED */

.section1-item::before {
  content: url('https://via.placeholder.com/90x90.png?text=Blanc');
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 18px;
  right: 18px;
  width: 12.5%;
}

/* ADDED */

.section1-item.active-card::before {
  content: url('https://via.placeholder.com/90/8f8.png/000/?text=Jaune');
}

.image-index-dot-active {
  background: var(--color-yellow);
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <div class="section1-col">
    <article class="section1-item active-card">
      <h3>Eco-responsable et original</h3>
      <p>La crème des prestataires sensibilisés à l’engagement durable.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="section1-item">
      <h3>Devis instantané</h3>
      <p>Obtenez le match parfait et votre devis en 2 minutes chrono !</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="section1-img">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/390x500/?space,planet" alt="Image 1">
  </div>
  <div class="section1-col">
    <article class="section1-item">
      <h3>100% Transparent</h3>
      <p>Nos frais de service sont transparents et sans surcoût sur vos prestations.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="section1-item">
      <h3>Accompagnement personnalisé</h3>
      <p>Nous vous accompagnons de A à Z avant et pendant votre événement.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="image-index">
    <div class="image-index-dot image-index-dot-active"></div>
    <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
    <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
    <div class="image-index-dot"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close. I did not actually test this code because I did not have the html.

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".section1-item");
const cardImages = document.querySelectorAll(".section1-item img");
const cardDots = document.querySelectorAll(".image-index-dot");


for (let [index, card] of cards.entries()) {
  card.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("bon");
    if (!card.classList.contains("active-card")) {
      // remove the class from all the cards
      for (let innerCard of cards) {
        innerCard.classList.remove("active-card");
      }
      // not sure why the img src is being set twice
      cardImages[index].src = "images/tcheen-logo-white.png";
      card.classList.add("active-card");
      cardImages[index].src = "images/tcheen-logo-jaune.png";
      
      for (let dot of cardDots) {
        dot.classList.add("image-index-dot-active");
      }
      cardDots[index].add("image-index-dot-active");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it doesn't seem to work. I edited my post to add more info and to add the HTML and CSS for you to have a visual of what I'm working with. I hope we will find a solution with your help :)

Comment: It looks like the other solutions offered should solve your issue.

Comment: They do, thanks for trying to help me though !